# Is the constructor for global.process stored anywhere besides global.process.constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to see if the constructor for `global.process` in Node.js is stored anywhere.

In the web, for example, constructors are easily available. For example, the constructor for `window` is `window.Window`. All constructors seem to be stored on the global (`window`). Is there any such place for constructors of builtin objects in Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window` 's constructor is `window.Window`

But `window.Window` 's constructor is native code which is not exposed

In node, `global.process` 's constructor is `global.process` function. 
But `console` 's constructor is `Console` function.

Incase of process, since the names of object and its constructor are same including the case (unlike in Window), the namespace of **process Function** is overridden by **process object**. So once the process is bootstrapped and node environment is established there is no way to access the constructor.

Only way to access is

```
var prc = new global.process.constructor
```

This will create a new `process{}` but is use less 'coz there's nothing inherited prototypically from `process` function except those inherited from `Object` .

Comment: `window.Window` 's constructor is `Function`.

Comment: True. What I meant was `window.Window.constructor.toString()` will not expose any code.